# Logitech H600 wireless headphones no sound?

Tags: microphone, headphones, logitech

I received a Logitech H600 headphone set as a gift.

When I plug it in to my Ubuntu 12.04 computer, it shows in the sound preferences as both a sound input device and output device. I can select it, but I cannot get any sound from it.

Does this headset work on Ubuntu, and if so, what do you have to do to get it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, when you see this headphone model under the sound as an input device and an output device, you simply have to pair the headset to the antenna if you are using it for the first time. Unfortunately, you need to use a Windows computer to do this, but after that it will work under Ubuntu. (I tried the utility under wine, but it didn't detect the device).

Plug the reciever into a Windows computer, and download the [pairing utility](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/8391?section=downloads&crid=407) and start the utility.

Switch the headset on. Then, hold down the Volume up and Mute buttons on the headset until the LED blinks green quickly.

Then, click next on the pairing utility. After a few seconds, it should tell you the headset is ready to use.

When you unplug the receiver from the windows computer and plug it into the Ubuntu, you will have to switch the headphones off and then back on.

Thanks to [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?s=70f82aa43a19c43ee2d913616eb628e7&p=12315285&postcount=6) for the answer that eventually worked for me, and see [this page](http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/26661/section/troubleshoot/crid/438/lt_product_id/8391/tabs/1,3,2,4,5/cl/us,en) for the pairing directions on the Logitech site.

Comment: the pairing was necessary for me to make it work. I plugged it in a Windows 8 system that recognized the headset automatically without pairing but still the procedure seems to be necessary for Ubuntu (14.04 LTS in my case)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is necro. My old wired logitech went out and today I went to buy from Walmart a headset, all they had in the pc section was these h600. Amazing it's 9 years old, the profit margin on them must be high af now. Anyhow I'm Manjaro KDE Linux and they work perfectly out of the box, you just got to remember to turn them on with the slide switch. Next time I need to remember to look on the console aisle, because those headsets work too.

My system specs are:

```
Operating System: Manjaro Linux 
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.70.0
Qt Version: 5.15.0
Kernel Version: 5.4.44-1-MANJARO
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor
Memory: 31.3 GiB of RAM
```

TL;DR
Works great on Manjaro 2020 KDE no black magic required

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and all I had to do is have the power switch on the headset switched on before plugging the USB transmitter into the computer.